# D3 multiple drag handlers

Tags: javascript, d3.js, d3-force-directed

Is it possible to have more than one element with a `.call(drag)` on it in a force graph?

In my example I have `<circle/>`s and `<rect/>`s. The `<circle/>`s are part of my force simulation and the `<rect/>`s are not. I would like to be able to drag both of them, using separate drag handlers of course. The `<circle/>`s are draggable but the `<rect/>`s are not. According to some examples I've found it seems totally possible to have a drag event that is not part of a force simulation. But I have no evidence of them working in tandem.

Related fiddle:

The circular nodes are draggable but the squares in the top left of the graph are not.
How can I make both of them draggable? I do not want the squares as part of the simulation as I do not want the forces applied to them.

https://jsfiddle.net/jrymer/ftv94rzk/53/

Answer (score 0):

Seems even though the `simulation` does not use the `data`, I still need to respect the `simulation`'s internal timer and use it's `tick` function to reposition as I drag. I have update the original fiddle to reflect this. The rectangles I added do not effect the nodes force wise, but can still be dragged, which was my goal.